# iOS CoreBluetooth state unsupported when using in iOS custom keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, custom-keyboard

I want to use `CoreBluetooth` API within iOS keyboard extension (custom keyboard). However, the state for the `CBCentralManager` is unsupported. The device I use is iPhone 6. It works fine inside the container app. Does this mean that the `CoreBluetooth` API cannot be used inside the keyboard extension?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set `RequestOpenAccess` to YES in your extension's plist under NSExtension > NSExtensionAttributes.

Setting this to YES allows the extension to access network resources. Bluetooth is considered a network resource so you will get `CBManagerStateUnsupported` when `RequestOpenAccess` is NO.

Comment: Note that the attribute name is `RequestsOpenAccess` with an s. [RequestsOpenAccess](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW24)